# Java function on function

Tags: java, class

I'm used a Java API for a game to code plugins for it where I saw like a function on function:

```
getQuestion().getTitle();
```

How do I make a class like this that I can do for example:

```
getUserData()
```

That wil gives:

```
user: joey
age: 17
lang: Dutch
```

and when I want some data I could use:

```
getUserData().getUser(); // Returns user
getUserData().getAge(); // Returns age
getUserData().getLang(); // Returns language
```

So how could I make a class to do something like that function on function?