# Java function on following function

Tags: java, methods

Yesterday I made this question: [Java function on function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291832/java-function-on-function?noredirect=1#comment48680216_30291832)

For help and get marked as Duplicate but I think I didn't get understand there what I want and now I try again.

I want methods can be only called on methods for example we have the class Roads and on the road we will go a Way.

```
Roads.Way1()
```

After we choose the Way1 we will go to Path1

```
Roads.Way1().Path1()
```

But if we choose Way2

```
Roads.Way2()
```

We are not able to go to Path1() cause Way2() goes to Garden1() so

```
Roads.Way2().Garden1()
```

So what I try to say you can only use the methods(functions) in a wanted way and I saw this on different API or Library. So for the good understanding

Way1 goes to Path1 and **ISN't able** to go to Garden1

Way2 goes to Garden1 and **ISN't able** to go to Path1

So how to manager that I can make different roads that has there own ways so I could make like

```
Roads.Way1().
/* 
Goes to: 
Path1()
Fountain()
Market()
*/
```

And Way to cant access them and can only use there own destinations.

Comment: return a different object with specific methods

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking for is: how can I express "control flow" using "language features". And well, there would be ways to get there: you would need a lot of different classes (or maybe interfaces); so something that is a "Way2" would simply not offer a "Path1" method.

But: doing so sounds like **bad** idea. It will work fine initially, but as soon as you start extending your system, you will be running into problems **all** the time:

"Hmm, I need to change Way2; it should now allow to go Path1; but uups; there are some Way2-thingies that should not allow Path1; so I actually need a Way3-thingy" and so on. Chances are extremely high that maintaining this code will turn into a nightmare very soon.

I know, this is just an opinion, but my gut feeling is: you are looking for the wrong solution to your problem. Instead, you should spent time on identifying what your actual problem is; and then think about better ways to solve that problem!